# How to make union of different database tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two models: Games and Posts

In my controller I have 2 queries to fetch the Games and the Posts separately:

```
$posts = Post::with(['comment', 'comment.responsavel', 'responsavel', 'like', 'share'])
            ->whereIn('posts.responsavel_id', $follow->pluck('seguido_id'))
            ->OrWhere('posts.responsavel_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->orderBy('published_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(5);
```

```
$games = Game::where(function ($query) use ($arr) {
            return $query
                ->whereIn('time_id', $arr)
                ->orWhereIn('time_desafiado_id', $arr);
        })->where('games.grupo', '!=', 'Desafiado')
            ->select('games.*', DB::raw('CONCAT ( games.data, " ",games.horario ) as published_at'))
            ->paginate(5);
```

In the Feed of my application I run a foreach that goes through all the games and the posts ordered by publication date (mixed)

The problem is that in the feed I have a pagination system that only displays 5 items at a time (posts pagination) and the games consequently are on the last pages of the feed.

I would like to know a way to paginate the two mixed at once.

I thought of joining the two variables into one through the Eloquent union method. The problem is that because they are tables with different fields, I can't do this union.

I tried to do it by joins, but the two models are joined in one and the games end up being classified as posts.

Code of feed pagination:

```
@if($posts != null)
{{ $posts->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I replaced the paginate of the code with a simple get.

I ran a foreach adding all the games in the posts array:

```
foreach ($games as $game) {
   $posts->push($game);
}
```

After that I changed the boot method on AppServiceProvider.php file so that laravel accepts pagination in Collections and not just in Queries:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

public function boot()
{
    /**
     * Paginate a standard Laravel Collection.
     *
     * @param int $perPage
     * @param int $total
     * @param int $page
     * @param string $pageName
     * @return array
     */
    Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
        $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
            $total ?: $this->count(),
            $perPage,
            $page,
            [
                'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                'pageName' => $pageName,
            ]
        );
    });

}
```

Then it was just a matter of reordering the items and running a paginate directly in the Ready Collection:

```
$posts = $posts->sortByDesc('published_at')->paginate(5);
```